# How to pass json data through indent and bundles in android studio

Tags: java, android

I created my app using tabbed activity. I am passing json objects from server within the main activity. I am showing my output in the list of values fpr json objects. Now I need to add another layout where I want to show the detailed description of my app so I am using button inside the list. by clicking on that button it should pass my json values to another layout, for that I am using intent and bundle concept but it is throwing error. If anyone know about this please help me. Thanks in advance

```
btnPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("data",tvmername.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        /*---------------------*/

        public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

            private List<CarrotModel> carrotModelList;
            private int resource;

            private LayoutInflater inflater;

            public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<CarrotModel> objects) {
                super(context, resource, objects);
                carrotModelList = objects;
                this.resource = resource;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
                }

                ImageView ivIcon;
                TextView tvDiscount;
                TextView tvDealDesc;
                TextView tvOfftoDis;
                TextView tvmeradd;


                ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);

                tvDiscount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDiscount);
                tvmername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMerName);
                tvDealDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDealDesc);
                tvOfftoDis = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvOftoDis);
                tvmeradd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvmeradd);

                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(carrotModelList.get(position).getImageURL(), ivIcon);
                tvDiscount.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getDiscount() + "% OFF");
                tvmername.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getMerchantName());
                tvDealDesc.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getDealDescription());
                tvOfftoDis.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getOffersToDisplay());
                tvmeradd.setText(carrotModelList.get(position).getMerchantAddress());


                return convertView;
            }
        }

        /**
         * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
         * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
         */
        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                new JSONTask().execute("https://api.appery.io/rest/1/code/39aea091-00d8-4e02-af39-93d63f965d08/exec?ConponFor=normal");
                // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
                // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // Show 3 total pages.
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        new JSONTask().execute("https://api.appery.io/rest/1/code/39aea091-00d8-4e02-af39-93d63f965d08/exec?ConponFor=normal");
                        return "Deals";
                    case 1:
                        return "SECTION 2";
                    case 2:
                        return "SECTION 3";
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is that button is going to be used only to show the applications description?

Comment: yes and also i ll add some more fields

Comment: put some code mate

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c00ardof/1/
here is the code for intent

Comment: Iam having 30 objects in main list.. each object has a button.. if i click the button it should show another layout by passing the object values.. for ex.. in music playlist v ll have n no of song in list.. by clicking upon one sone it will expand and show all the details of the song by passing information to it

Comment: Accept the edit, I added your code here itself

Comment: I didnt find anything.. Iam not getting

Comment: Put that onclick inside the viewholder, and then instead of "data" pass each of the value from intent to another activity

Comment: getapplication() showing error as make placeholder fragment as non static.. bt by default tab fragments are inside the static placeholder..

Comment: here is the code; https://jsfiddle.net/c00ardof/2/

Comment: can you share complete code?

Comment: MainActivity : https://jsfiddle.net/goq7417m/

Comment: SecondActivity: https://jsfiddle.net/goq7417m/1/                                                    fragment_main.xml : https://jsfiddle.net/goq7417m/2/                                     row.xml: https://jsfiddle.net/goq7417m/3/

Comment: in row2.xml i want to show all the data from row.xml.. how to pass row.xml data to row2.xml????